# App Store Validation Issue - CFBundleIcons App Icon20x20

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been struggling with this issue for over a week. Whenever I try to validate a build or use application loader lately I have been getting this error:

```
iTunes Store operation failed. 
Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':'AppIcon20x20'
```

Now, the problem is there is no AppIcon20x20 key in my plist.

Here's my AppIcon asset and attributes settings: 
[AppIcon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyooc.png), [Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkmmY.png)

Nowhere is a 20x20 asset even mentioned in my Plist, as seen by the source code version here :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon603x.png</string>
                <string>icon602x.png</string>
                <string>icon403x.png</string>
                <string>icon402x.png</string>
                <string>icon293x.png</string>
                <string>icon292x.png</string>
                <string>icon203x.png</string>
                <string>icon203x.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>https://millsfitnessapparel.myshopify.com/</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And lastly, I have googled the heck out of this topic and they all say to just add CFBundleIcons to your plist, which I did, but it's still throwing the error. I have also done this in versions of this project where there are pods, no pods, workspaces, regular xcproj. files, and even with 1 view controller and just some icons [this latest build].

I have also tried to achive this build in xcode versions 8.1, 8.2, and 8.3, all receiving the same error.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. These are apps for a client and I am currently late on delivering because of this issue. Thanks.

Comment: `<string>icon203x.png</string><string>icon203x.png</string>`, shouldn't one be `<string>icon202x.png</string>`?

Comment: Just added a 20x20 icon and its still throwing the same error. Also @Larme I fixed that issue as well, still throwing same error.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically, that the 120px icon is not exactly 120px, I ended up recreating the icon and finally was able to get the app submitted to Apple Store.

Answer (score 0):

Okay non of the steps online worked for me so I'm gonna post how I resolved my problem, I had a very old project which was originally created before iOS 5 but it was upgraded up until iOS 9 but it carried over old icon system.
Even though I didn't have CFBundleIcons nowhere in my plist file and have everything properly setup in the asset manager under AppIcon key but it was giving this message so this is what I did

- I created CFBundleIcons key in the plist file by typing the exact key ( CFBundleIcons ) without selecting anything from suggestion window as that key no longer exist in the suggestion window.
  After you hit enter Xcode translates you key into 'Icon Files ( iOS 5 )'
- Then go to your project's target node where you can see the project's target settings.
- In there you should see the Migrate button shows up in from of the 'App Icon Source'
- Click to Migrate to the new Icon system ( eve though you may have
  already done it before )
- After you migrated create a new icon set in the assets manager or
  point to an existing one if you have already created one.

This should clear out that issue, basically we just needed re-invoke the migration process to clean up what was left over.