# App Store rejects because of app icon size

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, app-store

Appstore rejects app upload and shows this error:

> Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key
> 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon20x20'

Can anyone share what the issue is? I had implemented appicon using [this](https://appicon.co/).

Comment: Try generating icons with flutter_launcher_icon
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons

Comment: try these links : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521459/app-store-validation-issue-cfbundleicons-app-icon20x20 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584157/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-under-key-cfbundleic

Answer (score 0):

Use https://makeappicon.com website to make app icons it will automatically generate app icons of all sizes required.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first post on StackOverflow so bear with me.

I created this automator workflow, it generates all icon sizes needed for the App Store currently⟨sept 2022)

https://github.com/saxjax/app-icon-creator.git

1- Open in automator and save.

2- Create a squared  image 1024x1024 or larger using preview.

3- right click on the image, select "To Icon"
follow the prompts.

The script consists of blocks of 4 for each icon size:
1-Get value
2-Duplicate
3-Scale
4-Rename

If you need a particular size, just copy paste that quadruple and change the pixel size and the name accordingly.
Feel free to manipulate and share the code however you like.

In the future from Xcode 14 and out you only need to provide one 1024x1024 icon in your assets catalog.